Unity3D - What is the lighting set-up in the sample scene for the VR Core Template?
I've opened up the Sample Scene in the VR Core template (in the latest Unity version: 2022.3.22f1) and I'm messing around with it. I'm trying to see what differences there are between it and the old SteamVR package.
When I tried changing the skybox, the lighting broke. It's mostly white, speckled with black, and in some cases, orange/red:
enter image description here
That's after rebaking the lightmaps.
I haven't changed any settings except for swapping the skybox. Can anyone explain to me what is happening in the pipeline that is causing this?

Can you update the image? It's low res on the lighting properties and can't make heads or tails. Also what did you do with the skybox?

I dl'd the build you worked with, changed the skybox to one of the others within the project, as well as, a new procedural one, rebaked lights every time. Nadda. Sometimes Unity gets in a faulty state. Delete the library and redo things. Otherwise if you're using the GPU lightmapper, check the CPU one (yes it's slower) but you might need to take a look at your GPU for possible problems (or the drivers).
